# How can I make just one page of a Word document horizontal?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010. How do I set only the last page of my document to be horizontal? All other pages have to remain vertical.

Answer (score 102):

Go to the last page you want to keep vertical (Portrait) then select *Page Layout* | *Breaks* | *Next Page*.

[image]

Now click anywhere in the page where you want to have the horizontal page (Landscape) and go to *Page Layout* | *Orientation* and select *Landscape*

Do the same steps for the following page, the one after the landscaped one, but this time choose *Portrait*. Only do this if you want to restore the Portrait orientation back to normal.

[image]

Comment: It's a lot easier in Libreoffice.  All you have to do is use/create a new page style for that page (and for any other where you want the same effects) which is landscape.

Comment: This plays havoc with page numbers / headers and footers though

Comment: Not necessarily - each section has its own set of headers and footers, you can easily update the page numbers....

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/741549/how-to-i-set-up-continuous-paging-in-word-across-different-sections for steps to fix the page numbers

Answer (score 5):

You need to insert “Section Breaks” to do that. Then you can change the layout in each section without touching the other ones. There are multiple ways to archive this.

Go to the ribbon **Page Layout**, click on **Break** and insert a **Section Break** on the **Next Page**.

In the new section, you can change Layout, without affecting preceding pages. Afterwards, insert another **Section Break**, and change the Layout again for the succeeding pages.

If you are afraid of braking the layout of your existing document, *first* insert the section breaks before and after your designated landscape page *than* change it's layout.

---

Be warned, that section breaks can cause some strange behaviour to pagination, footers and headers. Sometimes it's easier to create the Landscape pages in a separate document and merge it after printing...

Answer (score 2):

If you want the document to start with the landscape page, go to the end of the desired landscape page, click Page Layout > Breaks > Next Page. This will add a section break after the current page.

Then, turn click anywhere on your *desired landscape* page again, and click Page Layout > Orientation > Landscape.

If you want to start with Portrait, and another page being landscape, do the same as above, but when making the section break, click on the page that is before the page you want to change the orientation of.

Section Break:

[image]

You will end up with something like:

[image]

If your 'odd' page is in between 2 normal pages (like above), then repeat the process but this time at the end of that page.