# Why does my whole document change page orientation instead of just a single page?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I want to make just one page in my document change from portrait to landscape orientation. I have followed the instructions for [How can I make just one page of a Word document horizontal?](https://superuser.com/questions/241799/how-can-i-make-just-one-page-of-a-word-document-horizontal)

However, the whole document changes to landscape orientation! How can I prevent this? I'm using Word 2007 on Windows 7.

Comment: You are probably using normal page breaks instead of section breaks... the instructions you link to work for me.

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg: yes, that was it, RedGrittyBrick *just* beat you to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page layout applies to sections. Normally all pages of a document are in one section. You have to break your document into three sections (two section breaks). Apply the page orientation to the appropriate section only.

For word 2007 see [scribd: Changing Orientation of a single page with Word 2007](http://www.scribd.com/doc/5298745/Changing-Orientation-of-a-single-page-with-Word-2007)

If you [show formatting marks](http://pcmcourseware.com/blog/2008/10/29/inserting-a-section-break-in-word-2007/), you should see two of `::::::Section Break(New Page)::::::`

Comment: Thanks. I did that (even with a blank document) and it didn't work; i.e. the whole document changed orientation.

Comment: @Wikis: Try following the tutorial in my updated answer.

Comment: That link is what I used before posting the question here. How do you, *"apply the page orientation to the appropriate section only."*? I put the cursor on the second page and still the whole document changed.

Comment: @Wikis: If you [show formatting marks](http://pcmcourseware.com/blog/2008/10/29/inserting-a-section-break-in-word-2007/), do you see `::::::Section Break(New Page)::::::` ?

Comment: Good question. Actually, I see ..............Page Break.............. That was it! I thought *Insert->Page Break* would do the same thing. But I had to choose **Page Layout->Breaks->Next Page**. Thanks!